# How to extract values one by one in a collection and then use it immediately to set other properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, database, nosql

```
match(n:User {name:"Ramu"}) with (n.bmrx+n.daily_avg_cal) as a

with a

match p= (f:Recipe {time:"Breakfast"})-[:is_diet]->(j:Diet{name:"Vegetarian"}) with collect(f) as d,p,a

with a,p,d foreach(x IN d|create unique (n:DietPlan {dp_id:"DP1"})-[r:contains {amt:(a*0.5)/x.Energy_per_Serving, unit:"No of Servings"}]->(m:Recipe {Recipe_ID:(x.Recipe_ID)}) )
```

So here it is, I want to extract the Vegetarian Recipe nodes from d, and use them one by one to calculate the respective Serving sizes ("(a*0.5)/x.Energy_per_Serving") , create new relationships between DietPlan and the collected Recipes and add the "amt" in there.
But this is giving an "Unbound Pattern" Error. I also tried with MERGE but that doesn't work because dp_id and Recipe_ID are Unique constraints.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You're binding some variables that are never used in the rest of your query, so we can drop p and j.

Since there's only one diet plan here, you may want to match on that before your more complicated vegetarian breakfast match.

Lastly, we don't need a forEach here, as you'll have each vegetarian breakfast recipe on its own row after your last match, so all that's required is to create the relationship.

```
match(n:User {name:"Ramu"}) 
with (n.bmrx+n.daily_avg_cal) as a
match (dietPlan:DietPlan {dp_id:"DP1"})
match (recipe:Recipe {time:"Breakfast"})-[:is_diet]->(:Diet{name:"Vegetarian"})
with a, dietPlan, recipe
create unique (dietPlan)-[:contains {amt:(a*0.5)/x.Energy_per_Serving, unit:"No of Servings"}]->(recipe)
```